# How to open a html document in browser like a pdf instead of downloading from visual force page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, pdf, html

From a visual force page on a button click i am opening documents using following javascript function

```
<button type="button" class="wpsButtonText" onclick="javascript:download()">I Accept</button>


 function download()
    {
        var params = getParams();
        if (params["id"])
        {

            location.href = "https://test.salesforce.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/" + unescape(params["id"]);
        }

        return(0);
    }
```

But the problem is of type pdf it is opening in the same tab instead of downloading but when the document is of type html it is directly downloading without any preview

For PDF

[image]

For HTML

[image]

is there any approach to make even html to open directly in the browser without downloading

Comment: are you trying to view document record?

Comment: exactly i want to view the document in the browser which is of type html...

Comment: hey @rajasekhar Pls check my ans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround for above issue.

You can create a VF page and get the document body blob data and convert into string. Now display in VF page. like below example

```
public class test1 {
public String strHTML    {get;set;}

public test1() {

       Document doc = [Select d.Body From Document d where Id= '01590000009jQTB'];
       Blob bodyBlob = doc.Body;
       strHTML = bodyBlob.toString();
    }
}
```

VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="test1" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!strHTML}"/> 

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: thanks Ratan,this is best approach i have ever found . Can u help me with soql query to fetch the document body from 'ContentDocument'.I unable to figure out how to fetch the document body from a ContentDocument record

Comment: @rajasekhar use `ContentVersion` field `VersionData` instead of ContentDocument.

Comment: `SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion where ContentDocumentId  = '' ` you can get the contentVersion using this query

Comment: Most Welcome @rajasekhar